# What is an "aggregate"

Tags: aggregate, d

Just recieved an error message that said "union __anonymous can only be a part of an aggregate". I'm not really puzzled about it because I was trying something that I knew shouldn't work.

But it makes me wonder what the exact definition is of an "aggregate" in D. I'm guessing it is a type that can contain other types, like an array, struct or class. Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An aggregate is a struct or class.  The idea is that you can't have an anonymous union as a local or global variable, only as a member of an object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in this context "aggregate" is used in relation to an instance-level relationship. In UML terms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Aggregation . So, in the simplest terms - "aggregate" means a member of a user-defined type that is of some other user-defined type (thus establishes a special "link" between two user-defined types).